# Getting rsync to delete files from the *sender* after transfer

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, file-transfer, command-line-interface

I'm using rsync to move one directory to another. Is there some way to get rsync to incrementally delete a file from the **sender** after it has copied it to the reciever?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(answering my own question here :) )

The `--remove-source-files` will do this. :)

Comment: Thank you. By this option files just delete. How to delete directories with file deletion?

Comment: @shgnInc -- there's no option in rsync that will prune the empty directories for you. Use something like `find /your/path -type d -empty -exec rm -rf {} \;` after rsync is done to prune empty directories.